# Resharper 6.0 showing incorrect information in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

Before I go make an issue to Jet Brains, I wanted to see if anyone else has this issue. All my class level private variables (eg: _myvar) are showing twice in intellisense. (Resharpers intellisense).

The correct is shown like so : _myVar
The incorrect is also shown: __myVar

Notice the extra _ this only seems to be for my class level vars. I have cleared the Cache but it has not changed anything. I am pretty new to Resharper, so I am hoping this is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: thats not happening for me, using r#6 rtm 6.0.2202.688. Ensure you're using the same build. Try also resetting your *visual studio* settings, ie Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset Settings. 3rd: delete the .Resharper folders that sit alongside your project folders and restart VS

Comment: @wal That worked, could you place it as an answer so I can accept please?

Comment: glad to hear. could you specify which fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is not happening for me.

Try the following:

- Ensure you're using the latest build. (I'm using r#6 rtm 6.0.2202.688.)
- Reset your visual studio settings, ie Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset Settings.
- Delete the .Resharper folders that sit alongside your project folders and restart VS

Comment: I'm not sure which was the fix, I deleted the resharper folders, then uninstalled, then reset the settings after a fresh resharper install.